# How to convert a generator of objects to a generator of a single property of each object?

Tags: python, attributes, generator, wrapper

Suppose an api returns a python generator that yields Person objects

```
# Example person class
# p = Person()
# p.name = "Jane Doe"
# p.age = 25

people = api.get_people() # returns generator
for person in people:
    print(person.name)
```

*But* my consuming code wants an iterator of names.

Is it possible to convert or wrap the original generator into a new generator that yields an attribute of the object rather than the object itself? That is, yields name strings rather than person objects? If so, how?

```
names = name_getter(api.get_people()) # somehow wrap into a new generator?
for name in names:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Is `Person` a class? What is the original generator?

Comment: @Pto: Person is just an arbitrary example.  The original generator comes from a call to a 3rd party api.  The api returns a generator that yields objects.

Comment: Do you actually know how to write a generator? Wrapping another generator and handling attributes seems incidental to the problem.

Comment: @User I would merely like to find out what more is needed than "create a generator by using generator syntax".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" and similar mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-and-similar-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's easy, this makes a new generator that wraps the original one:

```
def get_names():
  for person in api.get_people():
    yield person.name
```

Can also be achieved with [Generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (aka generator comprehensions):

```
# (<expression> for <var> in <iterable> if <condition>)

names = (p.name for p in api.get_people())
```